# Socket.io or Rest API

Tags: node.js, vue.js, socket.io, rest

I develop an application like Whatsapp using Vuejs and Nodejs. Can I create a backend for the entire application with Socket.io? Is it possible with Socket.io Rest api? I think there should be a Rest api in parts like the login. Is it true that I prepare parts like login with socket.io? Thanks in advance.

Comment: due to the nature of how vue loads its assets your need an endpoint for them and index.html etc, but theoretically yes you could use it to do everything, though its not practical, https://replit.com/@lcherone/66833860

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a framework like NestJs or Adonis (or many others). Those that I'm mentioning are ready to build a REST service and also use websockets (with socket.io).

It is normal to use both in a project. The socket will be an open and persistent connection to the server, in the other case the http request is a petition, so ask yourself, Does this feature need constant communication with the server or could I ask for something and thats it??

Note: You can create a whole server using only sockets (socket.io in your case) but I think that a combination of ws + http is better

Comment: fielding paper ( rest ) is always there https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm if you want deeper dive into rest..  if you need server push for events like " onUpdateBy-some-other-chatroom-participant" then you will need sockets. if you can subsist on only query response protocol then its just rest.